# Storing TextArea data with line breaks in database and displaying in same format with line breaks

Tags: java, database, jsp, textarea, line-breaks

I have a JSP page with a textarea HTML component. When a user presses enter and goes to next line while typing in textarea,and when he clicks save button, it saves the data from the text area to the database. But when I load the content of the database, the line breaks are gone. Means:

HELLO
WORLD

is displaying like

HELLO WORLD

I tried the method given here [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/replace-all-line-break-in-a-string-with-br-tag-in-javascript)
but its not working. I also tried this one [How to save user-entered line breaks from a TextArea to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database) but I am not using PHP and also the solution given here for another languages to replace "\n" with "<br />" also not working. Please anyone have any idea how to do that?

I tried this code:

```
String a=req.getParameter("topicdes").toString();
a.replaceAll("\n","<br />");
```

Comment: you just need to do encodeURIComponent($("#idOfTextArea")) in the request url in javascript and only get value by request.getParameter("textareaname")  and save into DB

Answer (score 3):

The replaceAll method return a new String. Your variable a is never modified.

To solve your problem : `a = a.replaceAll("\n","<br />");`

In this kind of method, reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is time saver.

Regards.

Comment: I agree with your point Eric but I also tried this String a=req.getParameter("topicdes").toString().replaceAll("\n","<br />"); So I think its same as of ur code.

Comment: can you show us the result of req.getParameter("topicdes").toString();