# How to insert a newline by pressed enter key into a database in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save user-entered line breaks from a TEXTAREA to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database)

When I press an ENTER KEY in a textarea it goes to newline. But when I receive this value from action page it converts to a white space. I want to receive ENTER KEY character as a newline from action page as not a white space.
Sample code : this is the HTML code

```
<form action="go.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="aa" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
<form>
```

Her is the go.php code :

```
<?php
$txt=$_POST['aa'];
echo $txt;
?>
```

If I input like 
"this is me(PRESS ENTER KEY)this is he(PRESS ENTER KEY)".
I want to the output as like 
"this is me(newline)this is he(newline)".
But I am getting from go.php like 
"this is me this is he". 
Here is no any newline but white space.
Please anyone help me. Why it is happen.

Comment: How exactly do you check it's not a new line character? Have you opened the page source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database

Comment: When I print this it always prints a plane string separated by white space. In page source it declare as newline but display as white space. But why I don't know. Please explain me if you know.@zerkms

Comment: Show me some hex or prove you understand what people mean by 'page source' vs browser outputting HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). This will insert HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string. If you are planning to store this in a database, you'll need something similar to `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the line breaks.

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

The HTML would look like:

```
foo isn't<br />
 bar
```

Your code would then look like:

```
<?php
$txt=$_POST['aa'];
echo nl2br($txt);
?>
```

Comment: "you'll need something similar to mysql_real_escape_string()" --- to be clear, you **always** need something "similar to it". Regardless of what and where from you're inserting to DB

Comment: @zerkms I am keeping my fingers crossed that the OP is using `PDO` or `mysqli_` functions and prepared statements.

Comment: yep. But I meant that your advice is too specific to newlines, while it's always required to escape the input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **nl2br** function to capture and replace newline. Working code below;

```
<form action="go.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="aa" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="s">
</form>
Here is the go.php code :

<?php
$txt=$_POST['aa'];
echo nl2br($txt);
?>
```