# html markup in form field does not work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, postgresql, markup

I am creating a site that a user can login and write or paste a text in a form field like so

```
<textarea name="descr" id="descr" class="textformfront"  rows="24" cols="50" required onFocus="cleari();"></textarea>
```

The text is saved in a DB (postgreSQL 9.1-extended with PostGIS 2.0). The data type of the column in the DB is "text". Then the text is displayed in the front-end, in a `div` like so

```
<div id="formdescr" style="overflow-y:auto; height:400px; width:100%;"></div>
```

My problem is that if the user insert a long text in the form, with paragraphs and breaks, in the `div` none of those is displayed. In the `div` all I see is a continuous text with no breaks, no paragraphs.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I use nodejs 0.10.12 / websockets to transfer from DB to browser and from browser to DB. I put text in the `div` like `document.getElementById("formdescr").innerHTML=descr;` where `descr` came from websockets in the client. In the source code I see no text. The user has to search first and then the `div` will get text.

Comment: How do you print the code? Are you using nodejs? What do you get when you look at the source code? Are the tags there?

Comment: Need to HTMLEncode your text.

Comment: @AlexBarroso I use nodejs 0.10.12. I use websockets to transfer from DB to browser. I put text in the `div` like `document.getElementById("formdescr").innerHTML=descr;` where `descr` came from websockets in the client. In the source code I see no text. The user has to search first and then the `div` will get text. I updated the question

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I updated the question. What do you mean `HTMLEncode`? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that browsers ignore white space in content.  Multiple spaces and new lines are all collapsed down into one space in the rendered output.

If you want to preserve all of the original formatting, with indents and line breaks, you could output the text into a `<pre>` block inside that div.

Your other option is to encode the white space into html entities.  Use `<br>` for line breaks and `&nbsp;` for spaces that should be preserved.

Comment: Works with adding just the `<pre>`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your solution very likely depends on the backend programming language you use, not the database. I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database) should answer your question if you use php (and if not, you should be able to do the transfer ;-) )