# Duplicate Text from Editable Field into Non-Editable Paragraph, without Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a simple way to achieve this **without a page refresh:**

1.) User enters a **PARAGRAPH** of text into an editable field or `<p>`

2.) User clicks a button

3.) Text is duplicated/copied to a non-editable `<p>`

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Building on the selected answer below, here is one approach to maintaining the paragraph line breaks;

Javascript:

```
function copyAddress() {
var x = document.getElementById("INPUTPARA").value;
document.getElementById("DUPEPARA").innerHTML = x;
} 

function addBreak(INPUTPARA) {
var textarea = INPUTPARA;
var matches = textarea.value.split(/\n|\s\n/);
textarea.value = matches.join("<br>\n") + "<br>";
}

function eraseText() {
document.getElementById("INPUTPARA").value = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="INPUTPARA"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="addBreak(this.previousElementSibling);copyAddress();eraseText()">Try     it</button>
<p id="DUPEPARA"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<textarea id="myTextarea"> 2233 West Chicago IL , 556699</textarea>
<p>Click the button to copy the address.</p>
<button type="button" onclick="copyAddress()">Try it</button>
<p id="copiedAddress"></p>
<script> function copyAddress() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
document.getElementById("copiedAddress").innerHTML = x;
} </script>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! Do you think there is a way to make it retain the paragraph line breaks?

Comment: you probably need to add a </br> tag to the textarea to have a new break line.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button onclick="start()">COPY</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function start(){
var text = document.getElementById("inp").value;
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = text;
}
```

or if you want to use JQuery

```
function start(){
var text = $("#inp").val();
$("#para").html(text);
}
```

You could also use [TEXTAREA](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_textarea.asp) with specified columns and rows

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="inp"></textarea>
```

For preserving line breaks you can put this

```
#para{
white-space:pre-line;
}
```

[SOURCE FOR LINE BREAKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database)

< p > is not editable by itself

Comment: Many thanks! This works well for a single line but I don't think an input form can accept a PARAGRAPH - Am I right?

Comment: @Ben

You can use Textarea as mentioned, you can specify it's rows and columns so it looks like a paragraph(line breaks at the end)

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="inp"></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text">
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">copy</button>

<p style="border:solid 1px #000;height:20px;" id="copied"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
        document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = txt;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution, it works very nicely for a single line. Can you think of anything that would work for a paragraph and retain the paragraph's line breaks?