# JavaScript to prefix <br> on selected text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `textarea` field where users enter in the information which then gets stored in a JS variable used to for a POST API request however since there are no line breaks as it renders into HTML, all the text is on one line.

How would I be able to prefix the Affecting, Actions Taken & Next Steps with the HTML `<br>` tag in JavaScript?

Current output:

```
Affecting: Lorem IpsumActions Taken: Lorem IpsumNext Steps:
```

Desired output:

```
<br>Affecting:
<br>Actions Taken:
<br>Next Steps:
```

TIA

Comment: You might want to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database.

Comment: Are you taking the input and concatenating it each time? if so just add the break tag to that

Comment: so basically I have a variable that is used as a part of my POST request. I need that variable to have the BR tag prefixed on the above headlines

Comment: Rather than trying to concatenate 3 inputs into one textarea - and having this issue - I wouyld strongly suggest that you split the inputs out into 3 individual inputs / textareas and then the value of each text input / texarea would pass as separate parameters to your POST query and problem resolved.

Comment: @gavgrif unfortunately I cant do that otherwise yeah it would be the best option. There are actually numerous headings that I need concatenated but this is just a small sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you want something like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('txt').value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'))
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" rows="3" cols="30">Affecting: Lorem Ipsum
Actions Taken: Lorem Ipsum
Next Steps:</textarea>
```

The text returned in your textarea-value has `\n` characters in it to mark line endings.  In most HTML elements these marks are ignored. You can make them visible in `<pre>` elements or even in "normal" `<divs>`s or `<p>`s if you format them with `white-space:pre` see here [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

In my snippet above I simply replaced each `\n` by a `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

A tag will show as the text of a tag and not render in a textarea, you want newlines.

```js
const val = 'Affecting: Lorem IpsumActions Taken: Lorem IpsumNext Steps:'.replace(/: /g, ': \n');
document.getElementById('txt').value = val;
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: That leads to dogy rendering - Lorem IpsumActions Taken: